# firstOrnew doesn't update existing records but inserts new

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello all I have a following code to update my table

```
$product = Product::firstOrNew(array(
    'id' => $data['product'][$i]['id'],
    'title'=>$data['product'][$i]['Title'],
    'isActive'=>$data['product'][$i]['IsActive'],
    'status'=>$data['product'][$i]['productstatus'],
    'user_id'=>$userId,
    'item_id'=>$itemId,
    'store_id'=>$store_id,
    'images'=>$images,
    'price'=>$price,
    
    'price_2'=>$price2,
    
    'stock'=>$stock,
    'description'=>$description,
    'country_id'=>$country,
    'manufacture'=>$manufacturer,
    'width'=>$width,
    'height'=>$height,
    'depth'=>$depth,
    'is_delivery'=>$isDelivery,
    'delivery_type'=>$deliveryType,
    'seo_title'=>$seoTitle,
    'meta_description'=>$metaDescription,
    'meta_tags'=>$metaTags,
    'articul'=>$sku
    
    
));
    
$product->save();
```

It does insert a new rows, but doesn't update existing once. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Please also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use update or create

```
$user = User::updateOrCreate(
                ['id' => $request->id],
                ['name' => 'xyz']
            ]);
```